# How to edit a specific row in Material UI DataGrid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datagrid, material-ui

Is it possible to edit a specific row in Material UI DataGrid ?

Don't get me wrong I'm aware you can simply add the variable `editable` in your columns but that wouldn't work if I'm using firebase data because if I edit it right there with no function what so ever it will just come back as before ignoring the edit clearly.

I saw they can do row editing in one of their [example: control with external buttons](https://mui.com/components/data-grid/editing/#control-with-external-buttons), however when I was looking at the code for reference I notice they are using `@mui/x-data-grid-pro` and I wanted to know if it was possible to do controlled edits with external buttons regardless of having pro or not.

when I try to use apiRef it says is not a component from DataGrid so I'm ASSUMING is pro otherwise I'm probably doing something wrong.

TypeError: apiRef.current.getRowMode is not a function

[image]

I wanted to test it first so I made sure everything fits and compile with no errors and then I was gonna change it to my liking but then I got that my code is a bit extensive so I'm just gonna add the relevant parts if you require whole code let me know.

**Imports**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import {db} from './firebase';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import "./ListadoEstudiantes.css"
import { useGridApiRef, DataGrid, esES,
  GridToolbarContainer, GridToolbarFilterButton,GridActionsCellItem, GridToolbarDensitySelector} from '@mui/x-data-grid';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Button, Container } from "@material-ui/core";
import { IconButton} from '@mui/material';
import PersonAddIcon from '@mui/icons-material/PersonAddSharp';
import ShoppingCartSharpIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ShoppingCartSharp';
import EditSharpIcon from '@mui/icons-material/EditSharp';
import EditIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Edit';
import CancelIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Close';
import DeleteIcon from '@mui/icons-material/DeleteOutlined';
import SaveIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Save';
import DeleteOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/DeleteOutlined';
import { Box } from '@mui/system';
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';
```

**Variables and Functions**

```
const defaultTheme = createTheme();
const useStyles = makeStyles(
  (theme) => ({
    actions: {
      color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
    },
    textPrimary: {
      color: theme.palette.text.primary,
    },
  }),
  { defaultTheme },
);

const apiRef = useGridApiRef();
const classes = useStyles();
const [editRowsModel, setEditRowsModel] = React.useState({});

 function CustomToolbar() {
  return (
    <GridToolbarContainer>
      <GridToolbarFilterButton />
      <GridToolbarDensitySelector />
    </GridToolbarContainer>
  );
}

function EditToolbar(props) {
  const { apiRef } = props;
}

EditToolbar.propTypes = {
  apiRef: PropTypes.shape({
    current: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  }).isRequired,
};

  const handleRowEditStart = (params, event) => {
    event.defaultMuiPrevented = true;
  };

  const handleRowEditStop = (params, event) => {
    event.defaultMuiPrevented = true;
  };

  const handleEditClick = (id) => (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    apiRef.current.setRowMode(id, 'edit');
  };

  const handleSaveClick = (id) => (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    apiRef.current.commitRowChange(id);
    apiRef.current.setRowMode(id, 'view');

    const row = apiRef.current.getRow(id);
    apiRef.current.updateRows([{ ...row, isNew: false }]);
  };

  const handleDeleteClick = (id) => (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    apiRef.current.updateRows([{ id, _action: 'delete' }]);
  };

  const handleCancelClick = (id) => (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    apiRef.current.setRowMode(id, 'view');

    const row = apiRef.current.getRow(id);
    if (row.isNew) {
      apiRef.current.updateRows([{ id, _action: 'delete' }]);
    }
  };
```

**Edit and Delete Buttons** from Material UI

```
{
      field: 'actions',
      type: 'actions',
      headerName: 'Actions',
      width: 100,
      cellClassName: classes.actions,
      getActions: ({ id }) => {
        const isInEditMode = apiRef.current.getRowMode(id) === 'edit';

        if (isInEditMode) {
          return [
            <GridActionsCellItem
              icon={<SaveIcon />}
              label="Save"
              onClick={handleSaveClick(id)}
              color="primary"
            />,
            <GridActionsCellItem
              icon={<CancelIcon />}
              label="Cancel"
              className={classes.textPrimary}
              onClick={handleCancelClick(id)}
              color="inherit"
            />,
          ];
        }

        return [
          <GridActionsCellItem
            icon={<EditIcon />}
            label="Edit"
            className={classes.textPrimary}
            onClick={handleEditClick(id)}
            color="inherit"
          />,
          <GridActionsCellItem
            icon={<DeleteIcon />}
            label="Delete"
            onClick={handleDeleteClick(id)}
            color="inherit"
          />,
        ];
      },
    },
```

I had another delete button that works with firebase and I was planning on using the one that Material UI show in that example because it looked "cleaner" but if is not possible then this was my other options was planning on doing an edit similar to this delete is way less complicated someone provide it before when I was trying to delete data from firebase in the Material UI DataGrid because it was deleting but not updating to firebase, but haven't figure out how to make rows editable because I got the error I show before and it doesn't let me play/test things on the code.

```
{field: "edit", width: 70, sortable: false, disableColumnMenu: true,
      renderHeader: () => {
        return (
          <IconButton
          onClick={() => {
            const selectedIDs = new Set(selectionModel);
            estudiantes.filter((x) =>
            selectedIDs.has(x.id)).map( x => {
              alert("test")
              const temporalQuery = db.collection("usuarios").doc(user.uid).collection("estudiantes").doc(x.id);
              temporalQuery.update({
                //update smart coding
                nombre: "edited name",
                colegio: "edited school",
                grado: "edited course"
              })
            })
          }}
          >
            <EditSharpIcon />
          </IconButton>
        );
      }
    }
```

**DataGrid**

```
<DataGrid 
        localeText={esES.components.MuiDataGrid.defaultProps.localeText}
        
        rows={estudiantes}
        columns={columns}
        autoHeight 

        pageSize={pageSize}
        onPageSizeChange={(newPageSize) => setPageSize(newPageSize)}
        rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 20]} 

        apiRef={apiRef}
        editMode="row"
        onRowEditStart={handleRowEditStart}
        onRowEditStop={handleRowEditStop}
        
        components={{
          Toolbar: CustomToolbar, EditToolbar
        }}

        componentsProps={{
          toolbar: { apiRef },
        }}

        checkboxSelection
        //Store Data from the row in another variable
        onSelectionModelChange = {(id) => {
          setSelectionModel(id);
          const selectedIDs = new Set(id);
          const selectedRowData = estudiantes.filter((row) =>
            selectedIDs.has(row.id)
          );
          setEstudiantesData(selectedRowData)
        }
      }

      onCellDoubleClick={(params, event) => {
        if (!event.ctrlKey) {
          event.defaultMuiPrevented = true;
        }
      }}
      />
```

**Code for Editing**
So far I was testing with this component for editing  I know how to edit by form is quite easy but I want to understand the editMod to row and edit rows right there without the need of going outside to a form

```
{field: "edit", width: 70, sortable: false, disableColumnMenu: true,
      renderHeader: () => {
        return (
          <IconButton
          onClick={() => {
            const selectedIDs = new Set(selectionModel);
            estudiantes.filter((x) =>
            selectedIDs.has(x.id)).map( x => {
              /*const temporalQuery = db.collection("usuarios").doc(user.uid).collection("estudiantes").doc(x.uid);
              temporalQuery.update({
                //update smart coding
                nombre: "edited name",
                colegio: "edited school",
                grado: "edited course"
              })*/
            })
          }}
          >
            <EditSharpIcon />
          </IconButton>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: `apiRef` is a pro feature, it's not available in the community version.

Comment: Oh... welp there go my plan of doing edit mode, is there any workaround for this ? like to edit rows

Comment: It's not very apparent from the [docs](https://mui.com/components/data-grid/editing/#apiref), the paid features have a blue cube next to the header.

Comment: so if I wanted to edit a row I would have to select one -> save value -> open a form -> search for the doc from firebase -> modify it in the form -> update firebase I asume

Comment: If you want to use inline edit, you can set `editMode` to row and execute some code when the user submits the data, or you can display a form dialog with the default values are the row data of the row you just selected.

Comment: What I want to achieve is that I do click on the checkbox and then I click on an edit button just like the delete button you helped me out before and then make it go edit mode that one checked row and then edit it and save it to the firebase that's my final goal, so far I have something like this (will update in question or should I make a new question ? )